# I got this JSON (this is a small snippet) from the alphavantage API and I need to extract only the close data but can't figure out how

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python (and coding in general) and trying to write a  program got to analyse stock market data. I got this JSON (this is a small snippet) from the alphavantage API and I need to extract only the close data but can't figure out how. How would I go about only taking the close data and retaining the date stamp?

```
    '2020-07-30': {   '1. open': '201.0000',
                      '2. high': '204.4600',
                      '3. low': '199.5700',
                      '4. close': '203.9000',
                      '5. volume': '25079596'},
    '2020-07-31': {   '1. open': '204.4000',
                      '2. high': '205.1000',
                      '3. low': '199.0100',
                      '4. close': '205.0100',
                      '5. volume': '51247969'},
    '2020-08-03': {   '1. open': '211.5200',
                      '2. high': '217.6400',
                      '3. low': '210.4400',
                      '4. close': '216.5400',
                      '5. volume': '78983009'},
    '2020-08-04': {   '1. open': '214.1700',
                      '2. high': '214.7700',
                      '3. low': '210.3100',
                      '4. close': '213.2900',
                      '5. volume': '49280056'},
    '2020-08-05': {   '1. open': '214.9000',
                      '2. high': '215.0000',
                      '3. low': '211.5700',
                      '4. close': '212.9400',
                      '5. volume': '28858621'}}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you tried? There are loads of pre-existing questions and answers explaining how to do this. JSON isn't anything special; you've just got a nested dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example, you should look up:

1. How to send requests.
2. How to work with Python dictionaries.

```py
import requests

# Sample data URL
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo"
# Get the data
response = requests.get(url)
# Convert the data to a python Dictionary
data = response.json()
# Get the 5 minute quotes from the data
five_min_data = data["Time Series (5min)"]
# Loop through each 5 minute quote and print the date and close price
for date in five_min_data:
    print("The date is ", date)
    print("The close price is ", five_min_data[date]["4. close"])
```